# Asymptotic Runtime of a weird for loop

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I am decent at solving runtime summations but this for loop has me stumped,

for (j=i; i < (n^2/i); i++) {...}

When I try to solve it I get c (constant) * n^2 * i^-1. Am I to assume that this runtime is O(n^2) or is it log(n) because it is halving i each time?

Comment: Where does the `i` in `(n^2/i)` belongs to? is it `(n^2)/i` or is it `n^(2/i)`?

Comment: `n^(2/i)` would be fairly evil, if you use a logarithm and squint a bit, that would be `O(log n)` I guess?

Answer (score 0):

`i` starts somewhere (let's call it `i0`), increases by 1, stops at `n` (see *), so it's `O(n-i0)`

(*): if `i==n`, then that condition compares `n` vs. `n^2/n`